# Prove that Koch's Snowflake Curve is Jordan Measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Obviously we can not prove this fractal is Jordan Measurable with standard proofs, making some rectangles and talk them smaller than $\varepsilon$ or something. The problem is of course in the infinite long boundary.

I thought maybe to use induction, but I'm not sure on what (the amount of straight lines? The amount of extra lines per step?) and how. Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is Jordan measurable iff its boundary has Lebesgue measure $0$.

(See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure#Extension_to_more_complicated_sets).) The Koch snowflake $K$ is bounded, and its boundary equals $K$ because $K$ has empty interior and is closed. Hence $K$ is Jordan measurable iff $\partial K = K$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

> The image of a smooth map $f \colon \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Let $D_n$ be the subset of $\mathbb R^2$ formed by drawing the $n$th iteration of the Koch snowflake. It is the union of the images of $3 \cdot 4^n$ smooth maps (which are just straight lines), and by finite additivity of the Lebesgue measure, $D_n$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Since $K \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$, it follows from monotonicity and countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure that $K$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

---

UPDATE: here's a way around the Lebesgue measure.

Let $D_n$ be as above. Each of the $3 \cdot 4^n$ segments of $D_n$ has length $\tfrac{s}{3^n}$ if our original equilateral triangle had side length $s$. We form a (finite) open cover of $D_n$ by enclosing each of its segments in an open rectangle $R_n$ which has length $\tfrac{s}{3^n} + l_n$ and width $w_n$. Any numbers $l_n, w_n > 0$ will do (we'll choose them later). Since $K$ is closed and bounded, it's compact, and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty R_n$ is an open cover of $K$, so it reduces to a finite subcover $R_{n_1}, \dots, R_{n_k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$. Then the Jordan measure of $K$ is bounded above via
$$|K| \leq \sum_{j=1}^k |R_{n_j}| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |R_n| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3 \cdot 4^n w_n \left( \frac{s}{3^n} + l_n \right).$$
Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, if we take $w_n = \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2s \cdot 3 \cdot 4^n}$ and $l_n = \tfrac{s}{3^n}$, then the above becomes $|K| \leq \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$ using geometric series, and it follows that $K$ has Jordan measure $0$ and is Jordan measurable.

Comment: Aha, the Lebesgue measure, I didn't know about that but after a quick google search, it seems to include Jordan measurability? I think a similar argument may work for Jordan measurability directly though. I think I can work this out myself, thanks! But fair enough, you answered the question.

Comment: "Since $K \subset \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n$ : that doesn't seem true. Only the endpoints on $D_n$ are also in $K$, so that would mean $K$ is countable